Understanding predictions from early rounds of XGboost
I have a dataset that I am modeling with gamma regression via xgboost.  The target variable has a mean of around 13,000.  If I run xgb.train with nrounds = 20, my fit metric improves as follows:
[1] eval-gamma-nloglik:19068.589753 train-gamma-nloglik:19214.349747 
[2] eval-gamma-nloglik:14126.776741 train-gamma-nloglik:14234.760451 
[3] eval-gamma-nloglik:10465.869439 train-gamma-nloglik:10545.868618 
[4] eval-gamma-nloglik:7753.880010  train-gamma-nloglik:7813.146760 
[5] eval-gamma-nloglik:5744.865650  train-gamma-nloglik:5788.775051 
[6] eval-gamma-nloglik:4256.630570  train-gamma-nloglik:4289.161127 
[7] eval-gamma-nloglik:3154.190101  train-gamma-nloglik:3178.297719 
[8] eval-gamma-nloglik:2337.566473  train-gamma-nloglik:2355.427432 
[9] eval-gamma-nloglik:1732.674952  train-gamma-nloglik:1745.907601 
[10]    eval-gamma-nloglik:1284.639146  train-gamma-nloglik:1294.441921 
[11]    eval-gamma-nloglik:952.802399   train-gamma-nloglik:960.065419 
[12]    eval-gamma-nloglik:707.048396   train-gamma-nloglik:712.430466 
[13]    eval-gamma-nloglik:525.066581   train-gamma-nloglik:529.055224 
[14]    eval-gamma-nloglik:390.324413   train-gamma-nloglik:393.284621 
[15]    eval-gamma-nloglik:290.585986   train-gamma-nloglik:292.780028 
[16]    eval-gamma-nloglik:216.774041   train-gamma-nloglik:218.400892 
[17]    eval-gamma-nloglik:162.168768   train-gamma-nloglik:163.375479 
[18]    eval-gamma-nloglik:121.791626   train-gamma-nloglik:122.687146 
[19]    eval-gamma-nloglik:91.956086    train-gamma-nloglik:92.619277 
[20]    eval-gamma-nloglik:69.927169    train-gamma-nloglik:70.418368 

If I run predictions on a validation set, the mean prediction of this model after 20 rounds is 194 - relative to the magnitude of the target variable (mean of 13,000) this seems absurd.  It isn't until around 50 rounds in that I get a reasonable result relative to the target variable's magnitude.  My understanding of the algorithm is that Tree 0 should at least produce a reasonable model, even if it's basically just an intercept with no real segmentation since a bad variable was picked for its cover.
Is there something I am missing about how boosted trees work or is this simply a lesson to be learned that if nrounds is too low, the model is basically meaningless, worse than an intercept-only model?

For anyone who stumbles on this I realized I was not setting the parameter base_score.  This defaults to 0.5 because logistic regression/classification is the default mode and this parameter is unchanged when using alternative objectives.  Setting this to something more reasonable gives reasonable bad results for early rounds of fitting.
